# Unable to locate the webelement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am opening the chrome browser then navigating to the login page of a website.
I'm not able to locate the Web Element for the username input field. This is my code:

```
driver.get("https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Account.action");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='stripes-95358526']")).sendKeys("saif");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with `By.name("username")`:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("saif");
```

And for better perform you can use `WebDriverWait` instead of `Thread.sleep(5000);`:

```
driver.get("https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Account.action");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement userName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("username")));
userName.sendKeys("saif");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used WebDriverWait in some of my code but it is not working where I am doing continuous clicks.

Answer (score 0):

The Id you are using is dynamic so it isn't going to work as is because it will keep changing. I would use the name of the element like this.

```
//input[@name='username']
```

Answer (score 0):

The id you are using is dynamic so it would change every time you load the page. So either use "name" as others have mentioned or if you want to use id then use following xpath :

```
By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'stripes--')"]
```